# how can i get dropdownlist id in controller when we select an item using mvc4

Tags: view

I have dropdownlst which i have filled from database. Now i need to get the selected value in Controller do some manipulation. But null data will get. Code which i have tried.

```
##View##
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {      

 @Html.DropDownList("SupplierId", ViewBag.PurSupName as SelectList, new  {@class = "form-control",style = "width: 200px;",id="supId"})         
}


## Controller ##


 public ActionResult ItemPurchased()    
 {   
       POS_DBEntities2 db = new POS_DBEntities2();
       var query = from i in db.TBL_Account
                   where i.Type == "supplier"
                   select i;
       ViewBag.PurSupName = new SelectList(query, "AccountId", "AccountName");            
       return PartialView("ItemPurchased", new List<PurchasedItem>());
 }


##Controller##

 public ActionResult GetPurchasedItem()          
 {   
     var optionsValue = this.Request.Form.Get("SupplierId");           
     return View();
 }
```

Comment: you have to fill the value in javascript in your .cshtml Please provide also the code that executes ItemPurchased method from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below changes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetPurchasedItem","YourController")) {      

 @Html.DropDownList("SupplierId", ViewBag.PurSupName as SelectList, new  {@class = "form-control",style = "width: 200px;",id="supId"})   
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />      
}
```

Controller will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPurchasedItem(string SupplierId)          
 {   
     var optionsValue = SupplierId;    
      //..............
     return View();
 }
```

It should work normally..